# How to change immutablejs Record with methods from derived class?

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I have 3 classes derived from Record. Definitions of first two classes are below.

```js
// Base.js
import {Record} from 'immutable';
import * as uuid from 'uuid';

export const Base = defaultValues => {
  return class extends Record({
    key: null,
    ...defaultValues,
  }) {
    constructor(props) {
      super(Object.assign({}, props, {key: (props && props.key) || uuid.v4()}));
    }
  };
};


// LOBase.js
import {Base} from './BaseModel';

export const LOBase = defaultValues => {
  return class extends Base({
    created_at: new Date(null),
    updated_at: new Date(null),
    deleted_at: new Date(null),
    isActive: new Boolean(),
    isDeleted: new Boolean(),
    publishState: new String(),
    ...defaultValues,
  }) {};
};
```

And this is my last class derived from LOBase and where my problem is.

```js
// Question.js
import {List, Record, fromJS} from 'immutable';
import _ from 'lodash';
import {LOBase} from './base/LOBaseModel';

export class Question extends LOBase({
  id: '',
  name: 'test',
  description: '',
  questionType: 1,
  title: 'title',
  version: new String(),
  customData: {},

  //...
}) {
  insertOption() {
    let index = this.customData.options.length;

    this.updateIn(['customData', 'options'], options => {
      return options.splice(index, 0, {
        someGenericStuff: [],

        // ...
      });
    });

    return this;
  }

  static MultipleChoice() {
    let defaultCustomData = {
      options: [],

      //...
    };

    let question = new Question()
      .set('questionType', QUESTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE_CHOICE)
      .set('customData', new Record(defaultCustomData)())
      //...
      .insertOption()
      .insertOption()
      .insertOption();

    return question;
  }

  // ...
}
```

I use `let question = Question.MultipleChoice()` to create a new Question instance. And when i use `question.insertOption()` it works fine. But when I do this in the reducer on the state I get an error saying **"A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch"**.

How can I achieve to change question object in the state? Should I clone original Record before doing that? What is the Immutablejs way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

insertOption uses [this.updateIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn) but does not return or store the result.
When you return **this** at the end of the function you actually return the same immutable Record without the changes.
So, unless I'm missing something here, you should probably go with:

```
insertOption() {
  let index = this.customData.options.length;

  return this.updateIn(['customData', 'options'], options => {
    return options.splice(index, 0, {
      someGenericStuff: [],

      // ...
    });
  });
}
```

The updateIn will return a new instance of the Record with the updated values.

You did not add your state structure and reducer (if you can please do), but you should be sure to return a new state object every time and not just changing the question field.

BTW, you are doing a sequence of mutation methods one after the other (set, set, updateIn). This is not suggestable from a performance perspective. I'd suggest replacing it with withMutations in the following manner:

```
static insertOption(record) {
  let index = record.customData.options.length;

  return record.updateIn(['customData', 'options'], options => {
    return options.splice(index, 0, {
      someGenericStuff: [],

      // ...
    });
  });
}

static MultipleChoice() {
  // ...
  let question = new Question();
  question.withMutations(record => {
    record.merge({
     questionType: QUESTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE_CHOICE,
     customData: new Record(defaultCustomData)()
    })
    Question.insertOption(record);
  })
  return question;
}
```